# Group by integer count

Tags: java, count, java-stream

I have a `List` of `Integer`s and I'm trying to count the frequency of each number using the streams API:

```
// List looks like [5,6]

Map<String, Long> map = array.stream()
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::valueOf, Collectors.counting())
);
```

However, compilation fails with the below:

```
error: incompatible types: inference variable K has incompatible bounds
                .collect(
                        ^
    equality constraints: String
    lower bounds: Integer
```

How do I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: `Map<Integer, Long>` instead !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resulting map has a `String` as key, not an `Integer`.

Either convert it to a string:

```java
Map<String, Long> map = array.stream()
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::toString, Collectors.counting())
);
```

or use an `Integer` as the key:

```java
Map<Integer, Long> map = array.stream()
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    
    Map<Integer, Long> result = list.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    
    System.out.println(result);
    
    
}
```

Result is :{1=2, 2=2, 3=1, 4=1}

I think that the problem is with that that Map is declared as <String, Long>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your map type: Map<String, Long> mismatch Map<Integer,Long>

```
Map<String, Long> map = array.stream()
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::valueOf, Collectors.counting())
);
```

to

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = array.stream()
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::valueOf, Collectors.counting())
);
```